# Access a NTFS external drive in centos

Tags: centos

Is there any way to access a external hard drive with `NTFS` format in CEntOS 6.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

if its a usb, usually these get mounted automatically right?

```
/media/..
```

if you attached it later.

make sure you install the ntfs-3g package,

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/ntfs
```

this show do it..

either way.

```
fdisk -l
```

is really helpful to show you where the drive is.